# What kind of optimization problem is this? Is it a valid problem at all?

Tags: optimization

minimize $-r_1*r_2*...*r_n$
Equation constraint: $x_1^2/r_1^2 +... + x_n^2/r_n^2=1$
m nonlinear inequality constraint : $f_i(x_1,...,x_n) \geq 0$ $i=1,...,m$

I want to find the ellipsoid with maximal volume. The constraints limit the size of the ellipsoid, they are functions with n variable.

Comment: Try to type out the problem using MathJax. You'll probably get more responses that way.

Comment: What make you think it is not a valid problem?

Comment: A standard optimization problem has decision variables and constraints, which are functions of the decision variables. Here my decision variables are $r_1,..., r_n$, but the constraints are functions of $x_1,...x_n$. So I think I have to get rid of either of those.